# Increase Spark memory when using local[*]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

**How do I increase Spark memory when using local[*]?**

I tried setting the memory like this:

```
  val conf = new SparkConf()
    .set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")
    .set("spark.driver.memory", "4g")
    .setMaster("local[*]")
    .setAppName("MyApp")
```

But I still get:

```
MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 524.1 MB
```

Does this have something to do with:

```
.setMaster("local[*]")
```

Comment: Have you tried increasing `spark.executor.memory`?

Comment: .setMaster("local[*]") is for using the available core at local machine for doing the processing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to solve this by running SBT with:

```
sbt -mem 4096
```

However the MemoryStore is half the size.  Still looking into where this fraction is.

Comment: Total storage memory is calculated by spark.storage.memoryFraction * spark.storage.safetyFraction - which are 0.6 and 0.9 by default

Comment: This answer is not correct. This is not how you increase memory when you are running your app in a standalone local cluster. Nevertheless the comments of @Gillespie are very useful + his answer is the way to do it!

Comment: @eliasah Read my comments.

Answer (score 12):

Assuming that you are using the spark-shell.. setting the spark.driver.memory in your application isn't working because your driver process has already started with default memory.

You can either launch your spark-shell using:

```
./bin/spark-shell --driver-memory 4g
```

or you can set it in spark-defaults.conf:

```
spark.driver.memory 4g
```

If you are launching an application using spark-submit, you must specify the driver memory as an argument:

```
./bin/spark-submit --driver-memory 4g --class main.class yourApp.jar
```

Comment: I am not using the shell.

Comment: then you need to provide the driver memory as an argument when launching your application. The point is that by the time your SparkConf is read in your application - it's too late.

Comment: So it should go in SBT?

Comment: Are you launching your application as in the last paragraph of my answer?

Comment: no.  ./bin/spark-submit is for the standalone mode but executing on the server/slave.  When local[*] is used the program creates its own context.  No need to have the server/slave setup, so there is no spark-submit.

Comment: try setting the driver memory in the spark-defaults.conf

Answer (score 8):

in spark 2.x ,you can use SparkSession,which looks like :

```
        val spark= new SparkSession()
        .config("spark.executor.memory", "1g")
        .config("spark.driver.memory", "4g")
        .setMaster("local[*]")
        .setAppName("MyApp")
```

Answer (score 4):

Tried `--driver-memory 4g`, `--executor-memory 4g`, neither worked to increase working memory. However, I noticed that `bin/spark-submit` was picking up _JAVA_OPTIONS, setting that to `-Xmx4g` resolved it. I use jdk7

Answer (score 2):

The fraction of the heap used for Spark's memory cache is by default 0.6, so if you need more than 524,1MB, you should increase the `spark.executor.memory` setting :)

Technically you could also increase the fraction used for Spark's memory cache, but I believe this is discouraged or at least requires you to do some additional configuration. See https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.2/configuration.html for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change driver memory after application start  [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html).

Answer (score 0):

## Version

spark-2.3.1

## Source Code

org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkSubmitCommandBuilder:267

```java
String memory = firstNonEmpty(tsMemory, config.get(SparkLauncher.DRIVER_MEMORY),
System.getenv("SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY"), System.getenv("SPARK_MEM"), DEFAULT_MEM);
cmd.add("-Xmx" + memory);
```

1. SparkLauncher.DRIVER_MEMORY

> > --driver-memory 2g

2. SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY

> vim conf/spark-env.sh
>
> > SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY="2g"

3. SPARK_MEM

> vim conf/spark-env.sh
>
> > SPARK_MEM="2g"

4. DEFAULT_MEM

> 1g

Answer (score -1):

To assign memory to Spark:

on Command shell: /usr/lib/spark/bin/spark-shell --driver-memory=16G --num-executors=100 --executor-cores=8 --executor-memory=16G

Comment: you can edit this answer and include your other answer

Answer (score -2):

```
/usr/lib/spark/bin/spark-shell --driver-memory=16G --num-executors=100 --executor-cores=8 --executor-memory=16G --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize = 2G
```